# Hacker's keyboard v1.38.2 doesn't show any suggestions other than "Android"

Tags: keyboard

I downloaded and installed Hacker's keyboard v1.37 some months ago. It was functioning as expected and the experience was great. Then, I upgraded it to v1.38.2 and set the settings to the same for what I had for the old version.

The problem with he new version is that it doesn't show any suggestions. The only suggestion that I see when typing is "Android" and nothing else.

What do I need to do in order to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the dev has decided to seperate the keyboard and the completion dictionary. [Download and install the completion dictionary by searching `pub:"Klaus Weidner"` in the Google play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub%3A%22Klaus%20Weidner%22&c=apps&hl=en) and then, the suggestions will appear.

Quote from the [Hacker's keyboard app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en) description:

> Completion dictionaries are provided by plug-in packages, see the "other applications by this developer" section for the currently available list. The keyboard also supports use of dictionaries (but not keyboard layouts) provided by AnySoftKeyboard language packs.

Quote from the [English completion dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.dict.en&hl=en) description:

> In the future, the English dictionary will no longer be included in the Hacker's Keyboard package. Use this external dictionary to provide English completion suggestions.
>
> An English completion dictionary for use with Hacker's Keyboard. Needed for future versions, release 1.29 still has  it built in but I plan to unbundle it to save space.

Comment: Found it here: https://apkpure.com/english-completion-dictionary/org.pocketworkstation.dict.en